# Reboot with kexec without making it default and vice versa

Tags: reboot, kexec

Upon installing `kexec-tools`, on Ubuntu at least, I am asked if I want to use `kexec` to handle all invocations of `reboot`. I don't, but there are some occasions that I do want graceful termination of running processes and unmounting of filesystems and then execution of `kexec` to reboot the system. How can this be achieved?

And suppose that I someone has made rebooting with kexec the default. How would someone invoke a normal reboot in that case?

Answers should not be restricted to systemd.

Answer (score 1):

That is simple:

```
systemctl kexec
```

Comment: I updated the question. Please don't restrict your answer to just systems running systemd.

Comment: @Melab but you are running Ubuntu, and that uses systems, and the overwhelming majority of other distros that people actually use for productive stuff do, as well.