# Triggering a reboot sequence without actually resetting the machine/hardware

Tags: systemd

We do have machines that we need to reboot regularly. Unfortunately, the BIOS part / boot order sequence of the reboot process is awfully slow (about 10 minutes).

Therefore, I'm looking for a way to actually do a reboot without the "hardware part".

Back in the days with SCO Unix, a colleague shew me how to use run levels to achieve that. I can't remember how it was done and if it still applies to Ubuntu...

The closest thing I found was the use of [kexec](https://linux.die.net/man/8/kexec). But it does not seem to bringing down systemd properly.

Is there a way to use systemd to initiate the reboot sequence and restart without a physical reset?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reboot with kexec without making it default and vice versa](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/594691/reboot-with-kexec-without-making-it-default-and-vice-versa)

Comment: You do need to have systemd-boot set up, but on a system with 10 min boot time, which definitely sounds like server hardware, you will either already have it at least have no problems caused by dual-booting windows or such

Comment: @MarcusMüller these are definitely bare metal servers with multiple GPUs, multiple pxes... No dual booting either.

Comment: So, then, set up systemd-boot, and use `systemctl kexec` to reboot without hardware re-initialization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`systemctl kexec` goes through all the shutdown steps that `systemctl reboot` does, but replaces the hardware reboot through a `kexec` reboot.

You do need to have `systemd-boot` set up, so that it knows which kernel and how to load, but given your server-like use case, this seems not unreasonable.

Comment: `systemd-boot` supports only machines booted in UEFI. How can I configure machines with legacy BIOS?

Comment: you don't. that's ancient stuff. You wouldn't see that in server hardware, which this question is about, in the last ~15 to 20 years, so that's simply not a supported use case.

Comment: I beg to differ - I work in a company with tens of thousands of servers - 95% of them are still using legacy BIOS (including new models) since that's the requirement of our organization from the vendors (not sure why, but whatever). But I see your point.

Comment: @aviro kinda interesting, and kinda sad :) I bet that requirement stems from some legacy system management software :)

Answer (score -1):

Short answer, no.

Longer answer....

While taking the system into single user mode then back to default.target will restart most of the services, it won't replace the kernel after a patching cycle - this is the only reason I reboot hosts. Further, while it is posible to get into single user mode automatically, I suspect it may no be possible to get out of that state without manual intervention.

Check your hardware documentation to see if there is a way to change the behaviour.

Comment: Very possible: `systemctl kexec` goes through all the shutdown steps that `systemctl reboot` does, but replaces the hardware reboot through a `kexec` reboot.

Comment: @MarcusMüller: if you put your comment as answer, I will accept it.